# Get mtime Epoch timestamp with milliseconds from `stat`

Tags: timestamps, stat

If I'm using `stat` to display the mtime, I get a date with milliseconds:

```
$ stat -c '%y' test.log 
2019-07-04 14:32:10.730059167 +0200
```

However, if I want to display the Epoch timestamp, I don't get milliseconds any more:

```
$ stat -c '%Y' test.log 
1562243530
```

Am I missing something or will I have to patch it together from both outputs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the GNU Coreutils implementation, you can use

```
stat --format='%.9Y' file
```

or just

```
stat --format='%.Y' file
```

From the `info` documentation:

> The ‘%W’, ‘%X’, ‘%Y’, and ‘%Z’ formats accept a precision preceded
>   by a period to specify the number of digits to print after the decimal
>   point.  For example, ‘%.3X’ outputs the access timestamp to
>   millisecond precision.  If a period is given but no precision, ‘stat’
>   uses 9 digits, so ‘%.X’ is equivalent to ‘%.9X’.  When discarding
>   excess precision, timestamps are truncated toward minus infinity.

Comment:  Thanks! Didn't think of looking at it's `info` page, only looked at `man`. But it makes sense, since it's a GNU tool.

Comment: @finefoot yeah *sometimes* they hide extra nuggets in the info pages